# ImageView empty

Tags: android, imageview

I have a clean android studio (0.4.5) project where I have added an ImageView for the background. But somehow it isn't working. The image is showing in the designer but on the device.

Do you know why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: No. It just shows a White background in stead of the ImageView

Comment: Check logcat - there may be an issue with loading the image.

Comment: What directories did you copy the "desert.png" file into?  I assume it's in res/drawable.  But did you try also copying it into res/drawable-xhdpi, res/drawable-xxhdpi, res/drawable/mdpdi, etc...

Comment: I guess there could be issue of memory. You have large size of image

Comment: @selbie: Regardless of screen size and density the res/drawable direcory will be defaulted to if the image doesn't exist in any of the other directories.

Comment: Thanks. It was because the image was too high. I just assumed it would shrink it to fit the screen.

Comment: @Squonk - I've had my issues with that. ImageView sometimes doesn't load from res/drawable unless I copy the same file into a few of the density specific directories. I think the last time it happened I concluded it was actually a memory issue as a result of the image being too big, not a res directory issue. But I haven't had a chance to formally conclude that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the above comment that there could be memory issue `OutofMemoryError` because you might have large size image.